# How to bypass nuget version restrictions

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm writing an Asp.Net 5 (MVC6) web api, and I added the nuget package "SharpMap", which dependes on Newtonsoft.Json v4.5.0.0, but the asembly Mvc.Asp.Net.Mv.ViewFeatures requires Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.0.0.

If I update Newtonsoft.Json to v6 or  later, I get this error:

> Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures' with identity
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'
>   with identity 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

Any ideas on how bypass the version restriccion of the nuget packages? Or any other solution for this particular problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -IgnoreDependencies flag during install to get NuGet itself to install a package without worrying about dependency conflicts. In this case, it sounds like you would want to uninstall SharpMap, install everything else (including Json.NET 6), and then run:

```
Install-Package SharpMap -IgnoreDependencies
```

Then, we have to make .NET not complain about the conflicting versions at runtime. This can be done by adding a [binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx) to your web.config/app.config files:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NewtonSoft.Json" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-6.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This tells the runtime to redirect requests to load Json.NET 4-6 to load Json.NET 6. NOTE that the versions used here are .NET assembly versions, which are not the same as NuGet package versions!

However, it's odd for a package like SharpMap to have a strict version bound on a common third-party library like NewtonSoft.Json, though. Consider asking the maintainers to provide a version with just a lower bound on that dependency (e. g. 4.5.11 or higher).

Comment: I ended up creating a new slution and porting the relevant code. I also downloaded the latests sources and compiled them changing the newtonsoft reference version. But your solution DOES work. I'll contact the SharpMap publisher, because the released version on nuget is from 3 years ago, but the sources are only 3 month old.